# Was "Temple of Elemental Evil" ever updated?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, adnd-1e, published-adventures

The Temple of Elemental Evil was first made for AD&D, meaning that characters and monsters were still built for that system.  It is still ranked as one of the best campaigns in the system.  Was it or its character lists ever updated to 3.5 or even 3E rules?  I have found the "Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil" campaign, and it seems to indicate that it is meant to directly follow the previous campaign, albeit fifteen years later.

I am looking for anything official or any outside efforts on this. (Homemade documents, third-person PDFs, etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no official conversion guide or converted and re-printed adventure module for *The Temple of Elemental Evil*. But there is a 3rd party conversion on [ENWorld Conversion library](http://www.enworld.org/forum/rpgdownloads.php?categoryid=1). It is a fan-work and I did not check it much, but it looks pretty good for an old but legendary adventure module.

You can either examine the conversion works from above link or go to [The Temple of Elemental Evil download page](http://www.enworld.org/forum/rpgdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=44).

Answer (score 1):

While not a true conversion, every monster in ToEE has been statted under somewhat simplified 3.5 rules when they made the computer game of the same name.
Of course the spell selection of both enemies and allies is different and flying monsters aren't that scary anymore because all battles are 2-dimensional but (with a lot of work and experimenting, or with some modding capabilities) the stats can be deduced.

I know my D&D group did that with Baldur's Gate to learn AD&D, since they had no access to the books. So I deem it tiresome but feasible.